# CSS vs Attributes when using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When using to JavaScript to manipulate HTML, is it better to use HTML attributes or CSS (assuming that both did the same). Are there scenarios where one is better than the other? (length of code is unimportant)
 `<p hidden>Text to become visible later</p>
<p style="display:none">Text to become visible later</p>`

Comment: Attributes or css for what?

Comment: `<p hidden>` is invalid, did you mean `<p class="hidden">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key difference seems to be that hidden elements are always hidden regardless of the presentation:

> The hidden attribute must not be used to hide content that could
>   legitimately be shown in another presentation. For example, it is
>   incorrect to use hidden to hide panels in a tabbed dialog, because the
>   tabbed interface is merely a kind of overflow presentation — one could
>   equally well just show all the form controls in one big page with a
>   scrollbar. It is similarly incorrect to use this attribute to hide
>   content just from one presentation — if something is marked hidden, it
>   is hidden from all presentations, including, for instance, screen
>   readers.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-hidden-attribute

Since CSS can target different media/presentation types, `display: none` will be dependent on a given presentation. E.g. some elements might have `display: none` when viewed in a desktop browser, but not a mobile browser. Or, be hidden visually but still available to a screen-reader.

read [this](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/) article for more detail.